# Need help : URL Rewriting :

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need some help to rewrite my urls. Here are what I want to perform:

```
 www.mydomain.com/agencies
```

to

```
 www.mydomain.com/agences
```

Basically, I want to rewrite some of my urls because the website is for a French client. I’ve tried different things in the htaccess, but most of the time the result is a wordpress 404 error.

I am using a wordpress and permalink setting is set on  “post name”. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why don't you just change the permalink for the page/post as needed - or do you need the redirect in there for legacy links?

Comment: hey better thik is change go in post and write url manual as you need

Comment: The permalink structure is under settings and the actual permalinks are saved individually per post/page. You could look at a plugin for redirects https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/ but I am still unsure of what you want to do. Also reply here not as an answer :)